# jquery-ui-rails breaks rails test

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

I've added jquery-ui-rails to my project and it's working perfectly in the browser.

But when running tests they fail with an template error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error: File to import not found or unreadable: jquery-ui/datepicker.
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 6.0'
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker
```

**application.scss**

```
@import "jquery-ui/datepicker";
@import "jquery-ui/core";
@import "jquery-ui/theme";
```

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of `jquery-ui` structured the file library

Try the below

```
@import "jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker";
```

Hope to help